# How to format duration string like PT3M33S to HH:mm:ss

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, duration

i've been searching StackOverflow's posts about this specific date type, also i've checked on google's search engine to verify the name of this date type. So far what i've learned it's somekind of Google's date type format and i do not know the name of it (eg. GMT ..).

The date, actually "timer" i extract from JSON object and display it in the textView, and it is String type :

```
duration:"PT3M33S"
```

Browsing the net i've seen you have a date format and simpledate format but when i try to "translate" the format the PT doesnt stand for anything as the AM PM stand and it is translated to symbol "a" and like hours(HH), minutes (MM) ...

If someone can explain me what type of dateformat is this and how can i force it to display HH:mm:ss aswell in string so i can display to terxtView?

Comment: That's a standard [ISO-8601 format for representing duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Comment: I believe the best thing you can do is to get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the backport of JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API also known as `java.time`, and use its `Duration` class. `Duration.parse()` will parse your string. Unfortunately `Duration` objects don’t lend themselves very well to formatting, but there are a number of questions already on how to do, please search.

Comment: `PT3M33S` means a duration with no date part and a time part (T) of 3 minutes 33 seconds. You may think of P as standing for period.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

If you have gone through the above links, you might have already noticed that `PT3M33S` specifies a duration of 3 minutes 33 seconds that you can parse to a `Duration` object and out of this object, you can create a string formatted as per your requirement by getting days, hours, minutes, seconds from it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strIso8601Duration = "PT3M33S";

        Duration duration = Duration.parse(strIso8601Duration);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT3M33S
00:03:33
00:03:33
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).